# Как правильно сортировать Enum?

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка, enum

Например я хочу отсортировать `Enum`

**UPDATED:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Bean[] mass = new Bean[] { new Bean(new Object(), A), new Bean(new Object(), C), new Bean(new Object(), D),
                new Bean(new Object(), B), new Bean(new Object(), A) }; // 1, 3, 4, 2, 1
        Arrays.sort(mass, new EnumComparator());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mass)); //[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]

    }
}

class EnumComparator implements Comparator<Bean> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Bean o1, Bean o2) {
        return o1.key.toString().compareTo(o2.key.toString());
    }

}

class Bean {
    public Object data;
    public Enum key;

    public Bean(Object data, Enum key) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key.toString();
    }

}

enum MyEnum {

    D("4"),
    A("1"),
    B("2"),
    C("3");

    private String index;

    private MyEnum(String index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return index;
    }

}
```

Сортировка `Arrays.sort` использует `TimSort` или `MergeSort` время работы в среднем  `O(n log n)`. Но если мы используем конечное количество констант (`Enums`), можно использовать [сортировку подсчетом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC) за время  `O(n)`. Есть ли стандартный механизм для использования сортировки подсчетом для `Enums` в `java`?

Comment: Думаю, стандартного ничего такого нет

Comment: На мой взгляд, написать сортировку подсчетом проще и быстрее, чем искать в интернете (или в стандартных библиотеках) готовую реализацию.

Comment: Исчерпывающий комментарий. Думаю Вам и классы `Arrays` и `Collections` тоже не нужны, там "и так все просто, быстрее самому написать". Не надо изобретать велосипед))

Answer (score 4):

У деревьев Θ(log(n)). Это быстрее, чем O(n) или O(n log n).

```
Set<MyEnum> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(MyEnum::toString));
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values())); // [4, 1, 2, 3]
System.out.println(set); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Если операция `addAll` для вас медленная и элементов много, - set контейнер можно формировать по мере инициализации/загрузки самого MyEnum'а:

```
public class SortingEnum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(set); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }

    private final static Set<MyEnum> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(MyEnum::toString));;
    static { synchronized (MyEnum.A) {} } // manual enum class load

    enum MyEnum {
        C("3"),
        A("1"),
        D("4"),
        B("2"),
        ;
        private final String s;

        MyEnum(String s) {
            this.s = s;
            set.add(this);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return s; }
    }
}
```

**Updated:**
Из вашего нового примера, вы хотите отсортировать Bean по его внутреннему полю Enum, с учётом того, что элементы Bean могу повторяться. Тогда элементы Bean могут реальзовать интерфейс Comparable, где указать, что сортировка нужна по ключю Enum, либо передать компаратор в конструктор `TreeMultiset.create(new EnumComparator())` и можно воспользоваться Google Guava коллекцией `TreeMultiset`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.6-jre</version>
</dependency>

import com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortingBeanByEnum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMultiset<Bean> multiset = TreeMultiset.create(new EnumComparator());
        multiset.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Bean(new Object(), MyEnum.A),
                new Bean(new Object(), MyEnum.C),
                new Bean(new Object(), MyEnum.D),
                new Bean(new Object(), MyEnum.B),
                new Bean(new Object(), MyEnum.A)));

        System.out.println(multiset); // [1 x 2, 2, 3, 4]
        System.out.println(multiset.descendingMultiset()); // [4, 3, 2, 1 x 2]
        System.out.println(multiset.count(new Bean(new Object(), MyEnum.A))); // 2
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiset.toArray())); // [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
}

class EnumComparator implements Comparator<Bean> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Bean o1, Bean o2) {
        return o1.key.toString().compareTo(o2.key.toString());
    }
}

class Bean/* implements Comparable<Bean>*/ {
    public Object data;
    public MyEnum key;

    public Bean(Object data, MyEnum key) {
        this.data = data;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key.toString();
    }

    /*@Override
    public int compareTo(Bean bean) {
        return key.toString().compareTo(bean.key.toString());
    }*/
}

enum MyEnum {
    D("4"),
    A("1"),
    B("2"),
    C("3");
    private String index;

    private MyEnum(String index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return index; }
}
```

Comment: `TreeSet` это уже отсортированная структура данных, а мне нужна именно сортировка. А как насчет добавления в дерево по отношению к массиву ?  И как я помню `TreeSet` не содержит дубликатов,  у меня большой массив объектов

Comment: скиньте в pastebin.com, посмотрю что можно сделать. Например, формировать TreeSet во время создания Enum'а (вызова конструктора).

Comment: в коллекциях Google Guava есть Multiset - “Множество”, которое может иметь дубликаты; или RangeSet - Набор диапазонов; Если задача написать велосипед - то ничем помочь не смогу.

Comment: Вот именно что велосипед должен быть написан для `сортировки подсчетом` для ограниченного количества ключей

Comment: запустите таймер и посмотрите что быстрее будет)

Comment: скиньте часть данных, почему Enum так и не ясно.

Comment: Что-то ерунда какая-то. Во-первых, отсортировать быстрее, чем O(n) невозможно. Во-вторых, он сортирует сущности по ключу-enum'у, а не сам enum.

Comment: В чем разница  "он сортирует сущности по ключу-enum'у, а не сам enum"? Простая реализация: 1 проход создаем структуру Map<Enum,Integer> где integer позиция с которой начинается Объект с таким ключом. Второй проход заполняем второй массив.

Comment: Добавил пример с дубликатами

Comment: Все равно добавление в дерево  `O(log n)` до `O(n)`, а в массив `O(1)`, но все равно спасибо за пример. И, да, я все же искал сортировку, а не отсортированную структуру.